# How to find that a text file contains a specific paragraph in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Suppose there is one text file which contains a text(Example :-content of any website).
Now if I want to match a string **strA**, which is as paragraph, from the text file i.e the text in a text file say a.txt contains the string **strA** or not?

How to compare it?

Comment: In general: the content of a text-file is just a string(`File.ReadAllText(path)`), so you could remove the file-part of your question. Apart from that, your question is very difficult to understand. Perhaps you should show us better examples. Also, it's important to show what you've tried for two reasons: 1. we see the real problem 2. we see that you have tried anything.

Comment: Clarify your question and add what you've tried. Also, a text file containing "content of any website" doesn't make any sense. Look at this web page. How would that look in a text file?

Comment: @tnw: That part is pretty clear, isn't it? The "content of any website"  is it's html.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It could be, though if he means just a bunch of text that's part of a website, the answer could very hugely. It's ambiguous whether he means a HTML paragraph or a text paragraph.

Comment: @tnw: That's true. But if i have  to answer the question i would assume that _content of a website_ means html. If you need to find a specific paragraph  you should use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse the HTML then.

Comment: **strA** is in a separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic implementation of what you're looking for. There are vast improvements to be made.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the text files that contain paragraph.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="paragraph">The paragraph to check for.</param>
    /// <param name="textFilePaths">A list of paths to text files to check.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    List<string> FindFilesWithParagraph(string paragraph, List<string> textFilePaths)
    {
        List<string> foundPaths = new List<string>(); // list of paths to text files w/ paragraph

        foreach (string path in textFilePaths) // iterate through each file
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path)) // check files actually exist
                throw new ArgumentException();

            using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
            {
                if (sr.ReadToEnd().Contains(paragraph)) // read contents of file
                    foundPaths.Add(path); // and add it to list if it contains the paragraph
            }
        }

        return foundPaths;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
bool containsString  = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt").Contains("strA");
```

Comment: Here strA means string strA="Its contain a long string"